# Rootless dind running in a kubernetes slave, 'docker run' fails

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker, rootless

Has anyone seen / resolved the below:

I have a jenkins slave with rootless dind configured, all docker commands work except docker run, details and error below:

Error:

```html
    docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\"": unknown.
    ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

config and versions:

uname -a
Linux jnlp-5n7x4 4.4.0-1092-aws #103-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 27 10:21:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 Linux

docker info:

```html
Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: vfs
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: none
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  rootless
 Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1092-aws
 Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.11 (containerized)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.812GiB
 Name: jnlp-5n7x4
 ID: X54B:QFRO:NKMQ:YJMW:NEVU:QU2A:VDHC:RJBI:M3YQ:KUU6:C4N7:IXNN
 Docker Root Dir: /home/jenkins/.local/share/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by using a different default runtime for docker.

```
#update default runtime
RUN wget -O crun  https://github.com/containers/crun/releases/download/0.13/crun-0.13-static-x86_64 \
&& cp crun /usr/local/bin \
&& chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/crun \
&& chown -R rootless:rootless /usr/local/bin/crun
```

the service is then started with supervisor, config file shown:

```
[program:docker]
command=/home/rootless/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental --default- 
runtime crun --add-runtime crun=/usr/local/bin/crun --storage-driver vfs
autorestart=true
user=rootless
```

detailed discussion here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40068